# Error using ansible jinja2 template with helm values

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, helm3

I am using ansible jinja2 template to create values for a helm chart. I am getting an error
`template error while templating string: unexpected 'end of statement block'.`
This happens after helm uses the values file.
This is a sample format not the original.

The ansible vars file:

```yaml
apartment:
  size: "2000"
  floor: "10"
  numbers:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
```

Ansible j2 template:

```yaml
floorconfig:
    enabled: true
    aptnumbers: {% for item in apartment.numbers +%}
        - {{ item }}
          {%- endfor %}
```

Desired output:

```yaml
floorconfig:
    enabled: true
    aptnumbers: 
        - 1
        - 2
        - 3
```

Task :

```yaml
- name: Deploy version of helm chart
  local_action:
    module: kubernetes.core.helm
    host: "https://{{ inventory_hostname }}:6443"
    kubeconfig: "/etc/ansible/{{ inventory_hostname }}/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
    name: kube-apt
    chart_ref: apts/apt-stack
    chart_version: 26.0.0
    wait: True
    update_repo_cache: True
    wait_timeout: "10m"
    state: present
    values: "{{ lookup('template', 'templates/my_Values.yml.j2') | from_yaml }}"
```

Output Error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'template'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: template error while templating string: unexpected 'end of statement block'.
```

Comment: What does the the template task look like? What does the *output* of the template task look like?

Comment: I'll try to get the exact output of the template task. But I have added the task and the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making this overly complicated IMO.

1. you are looping over a list to recreate the exact same elements in what appears to be a yaml template. Why not using the list directly ?
2. you are going through a template to load back yaml values where you can just define the needed var.

You could just drop the template completely and simplify your value declaration in your task like:

```yaml
- name: Deploy version of helm chart
  kubernetes.core.helm:
    host: "https://{{ inventory_hostname }}:6443"
    kubeconfig: "/etc/ansible/{{ inventory_hostname }}/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
    name: kube-apt
    chart_ref: apts/apt-stack
    chart_version: 26.0.0
    wait: True
    update_repo_cache: True
    wait_timeout: "10m"
    state: present
    values:
      floorconfig:
        enabled: true
        aptnumbers: "{{ apartment.numbers }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

If you really want to go through a separate file, just make it an other var file, define the entire dictionary there, load it and use the dictionary in the value above.